# How I can fix error "No start date has been set"?

Tags: swift, ekeventstore

When saving an event in the regular calendar, the events are sometimes not saved. An error is displayed: `"failed to save event with error: Error Domain = EKErrorDomain Code = 2" No start date has been set. "UserInfo = {NSLocalizedDescription = No start date has been set.}"`, Although the date is determined correctly

```
func saveTaskInCalendar() {
        let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in
            if (granted) && (error == nil) {
                let event: EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    event.title = "Test"
                    event.startDate = Date()
                    event.endDate = Date()
                }
                event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                do {
                    try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("failed to save event with error : \(error)")
                }
            }
            else {
                print("failed to save event with error : \(String(describing: error)) or access not granted")
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you wrap setting the properties of the `EKEvent` in a dispatch async block, while you save the even outside the async block. This can cause the property setting to be executed **after** you've already tried saving the event.

Either remove the `DispatchQueue.main.async` call, since it shouldn't be necessary anyways or put the saving code inside the dispatch async as well.

```
let event: EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
event.title = "Test"
event.startDate = Date()
event.endDate = Date()
event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
do {
    try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
}
```

or

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let event: EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
    event.title = "Test"
    event.startDate = Date()
    event.endDate = Date()
    event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
    do {
        try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
    }
...
```